# QGIS buffer and CRS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I am working on a Project for an assignment. Basically I want the points on the map to have a three mile radius around them. The places are from a shapefile. Once I try to set a radius I am selecting the Place pin and using `Geo processing -> Buffer`.

I set the buffer distance to 1 and I have also tried setting the buffer to different distances and still I end up with the same sized radius. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: What is the coordinate system of your shapefile?

Comment: I agree, it looks like you are working with a geographic crs, for buffer (or anything distance realted really) you need a **projected** crs. 1 is here the layer unit, if its wgs84 e.g. degree/square degree. You want miles. So Project (save) your layer and change the crs while doing so (e.g. epsg 3395). Then it should work, also set the project to the same crs (right lower corner).

Comment: The project is set to EPSG:27700 British National Grid.
The Places Shape file is set to CRS EPSG:4326, WGS 84 
However once i change this to the British National Grid it doesnt work.

Comment: Working with mixed SRID's in a project is asking for trouble, you should bring project your data and bring it in the same coordinate system (you ll need it to be projected since you want to use 3miles as a unit) take a look at the question @wittich linked, that should work

Comment: Changing the CRS of the shapefile with `Set Layer CRS` does not work. You have to `Save As...` the shapefile to another file and CRS.

Comment: Thank you @wittich I used the method you linked. Worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that worked a charm. I followed this method - Possible duplicate of Understanding QGIS buffer tool units? – wittich